# Question 1-Million ...?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

**Congratulations everyone!**

We all love Stackoverflow! A huge personal thanks for a great site to Jeff and everyone involved :) ... I hope this question can be a landmark in the question time-line and a chance for people to put a stake in the ground marking classic and good questions for future and current users.

[image]

**Out of the 1-million questions, which is your favorite and why?**

(not improvements, that's for [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), if this isn't question 1m, delete me please!)

Comment: and then I am the 5th to reopen this!

Comment: It is CW :S ....

Comment: I really hope this isn't the millionth question, because it would be a travesty for a milestone like that to be tainted by an off-topic poll question.

Comment: @gnovice, I guess it really depends what you count towards questions.

Comment: @gnovice I don't like poll questions, but I think we can let it go for this particular milestone; at least it wasn't "how to parse html with regexp?" or "what is the best number?"

Comment: Let's not open this again, please.  Nothing wrong with celebrating 1 million, but the question for it _belongs on the meta site_, and indeed there are already several questions about the topic there.

Comment: @Joel: Sorry, I disagree. \*casts reopen vote\* This is "the" millionth question, after all. It has a right to stay.

Comment: It's nice, where's your heart! If it were on MSO it wouldn't be the millionth hehe

Comment: @Chris - It's probably not the actual 1 millionth question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3920758 , and question number is irrelevant here. Move it to meta.

Comment: @Joel: Now you're just arguing over whether the new millennium started in 2000 or 2001. ;-) I think the spirit of the occasion merits this post, but, you've said your piece and I've said mine, so I have nothing more to add.

Comment: The solution to make everyone happy is to have a competition on meta to come up with the best possible question, and then edit this one to be that question instead

Comment: +1 to further offset the 9 downvotes (as of this writing). Also, because this question managed to be closed then reopened then closed then reopened and then have 4 close votes (as of this writing). :-)

Comment: What a fuss .... sad really.

Comment: @Chris, there is an objectively correct answer to whether the new millenium started in 2000 or 2001. This millionth question thing is more subjective... hmm... fancy that....

Comment: Am so disappoint. All that time hawking the count and nothing better to ask than FIRST!!!!!!11111onesies

Comment: The lack of any humor or appreciation that 1m questions is a good time to look back and say something nice about the community is fairly tragic. I worry about the future spirit of SO. What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900149/most-under-appreciated-language-platform or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364/what-is-the-single-most-effective-thing-you-did-to-improve-your-programming-skill and more. The blind hypocrisy.

Comment: OOOPPPPPPEEEEEEEEEEENNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Here it is closed as noise and pointless, there it is closed as off-topic. The former is correct, it is pointless here. The latter is wrong. It is totally on-topic there. Please!!!

Answer (score 28):

This is my favorite, because of the instantly classic and amazing answer by bobince.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: +1 for Fosco, classic indeed

Comment: +1 - I had never seen that one before. Too bad it's locked, so I can't upvote it.

Answer (score 7):

My instant classic is this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920757/question-1-million .

*I'm trying to get a stack overflow.*

Comment: Not if you use tail recursion!

Comment: beat me to it. I was trying to find my other recursive answer to add that something extra to it.

Comment: Not nearly as good as this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67442/question-1-million

Comment: Looks like the community has optimised it out.